# Get toolbar button title inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-dialog

On toolbar there is a button. When the button is clicked a dialog popup's. In the dialog there are 2 spinner and a Select button. I need to get the current selected items of spinner inside Fragment. How can i do it?

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar;
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager viewPager;
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

//Navigation Drawer
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
NavigationView navigationView;

Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
Dialog dialog;
Button toolbarButton;

public String sp11;
public String sp22;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbarButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toolBarButton);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TimeTableFragment(), "MONDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TimeTableFragment(), "TUESDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TimeTableFragment(), "WEDNESDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TimeTableFragment(), "THURSDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TimeTableFragment(), "FRIDAY");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TimeTableFragment(), "SATURDAY");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

public void myDialogPopUp(View view)
{
    dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_design);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    MyCustAdapter adapter = new MyCustAdapter(MainActivity.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sp1));
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner2 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    adapter = new MyCustAdapter(MainActivity.this, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sp2));
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);

    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
}

public void onButtonSelect(View view)
{
    sp11 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    sp22 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sp11+"\n"+sp22, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialog.cancel();
    toolbarButton.setText(sp11+"\t\t\t˅\n"+sp22);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
}
```

---

```
public class TimeTableFragment extends Fragment {

public TimeTableFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "\nonCreateView", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_time_table, container, false);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own dialog and extend Dialog.
then add a method in your dialog:

```
public void setIndex(int index) {
    this.index = index;
}
```

and then in your activity:

```
dialog = new CustomDialog(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog_design);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setIndex(index);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your TimeTableFragment to get the two values.

```
public class TimeTableFragment extends Fragment {
    public void spinnerSelection(String one,String two){
    }
}
```

Now you need to get the current selected fragment from the view pager. For that use the following code.

```
TimeTableFragment ttFrag=(TimeTableFragment)viewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager , currentPosition)
ttFrag.spinnerSelection("Spinner1","Spinner2");
```

Put this inside the Spinner item click event.

Current position can be obtained by using the following methods

```
viewPager.getCurrentItem()
```

or

```
viewPageListener = new PageListener();
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPageListener);
```